# set dropdown value in other component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create this dropdown component :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{formTitle| translate}} *</mat-label>
<mat-select [(value)]="itemId">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
        <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
            <input (keyup)="getValues($event.target.value)" matInput [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" class="mb-2" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    <mat-option  (click)="emitdata(item.key)" *ngFor="let item of values" [value]="item.key">
        {{item.value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

ts:

```
export class SearchableDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() url: string;
    @Input() formTitle: string;
    @Output() selectedId = new EventEmitter<number>();
    @Input() itemId: number;

    loading = false;
    values: KeyValue[];
    title: string;

    constructor(
        private searchService: SearchableDropDownService,
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getValues(null);
    }

    emitdata(event): void {
        console.log(event);
        this.selectedId.emit(event);
    }

    getValues(event): void {
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        this.loading = true;

        let model = {} as SendDateModel;
        model.page = 1;
        model.pageSize = 60;
        model.title = event;

        this.searchService.getAll(this.url, model).subscribe(data => {
            this.values = data['result']['records'];
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
            this.loading = false;
        });

    }
}
```

and i used it in components :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
   <kt-searchable-dropdown [itemId]="304" [formTitle]="'COURSE.COURSE_GROUP'" [url]="url"></kt-searchable-dropdown>
 </div>
```

i pass to dropdown 304 item for pre selected it in dropdown . but it not pre-selected item 304 in dropdown .

how can i set the 304 item selected in dropdown?

Comment: Is the value of itemId being set to 304? console.log within ngOnChanges() hook will give the value of itemId. Everything else seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you are taking the ItemId using Input() you can always use ngModel to implement two way data binding.

For e.g. in your case :

```
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="ItemId">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of values"  [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

So, basically it will get binded in two way with variable contain data and will remain selected as you load the component.

You can read more about two way data binding [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

**Update**

ngModel should work. You have not wrongly implemented but its not correct way also. 
Your selected value only will come from [(ngModel)].

so your

```
[(value)]="itemId"
```

should be

```
[(ngModel)]="itemId"
```

complete code will be :

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="ItemId">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of values"  [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Try not to declare any div or component after mat-select if not necessary or debug one by one if its bugging to your component or not.